# Best approach to parse JSON responses in scrapy framework python

Tags: python, json, parsing, request, scrapy

I need to scrap 2 websites that returns a huge JSON (1.2MB) and uses the JSON + JavaScript to build the HTML. I wanna know what is the best approach ?

1. Use selenium to render the JS and scrapy the HTML

   |-> Not my favorite. Performance issues.
2. In the spider itself parse the JSON and create the items.

   |-> In this case, which library do you guys recommend  ?

   |-> Is this scalable ? Since it will be restrict to domain requests.
3. Save the JSON itself to item and build pipelines to create the items.
4. Save the JSON to a NoSQL or Queue and use other script to create items.

Thank you all.

Comment: use the builtin json library?

Answer (score 1):

As with most things, it depends on your objective.  If you want the most faithful html rendering, then you are pretty much stuck doing it in selenium or some other programmatic web client that can execute the javascript.

If you're just interested in the JSON objects, you might want to look into using scrapy or custom-crafted requests to obtain the JSON, then interpreting it with something like python's standard [json module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

That module can convert JSON to dicts pretty handily, and makes it pretty easy to automatically translate those dicts into other python objects using callback functions.

Unfortunately I'm unsure about the scalability of this approach.
  That's something you'll have to investigate further.

Comment: Yes, I have a performance restriction since it will crawling something  like 1~1.5Million pages. So huge JSONs could lead to memory problems. I think I'll use scrapy to fetch the JSONs and use a Queue Server to distribute the load among processes.